# Locale.US gives me Arabic street names when using Geocoder

Tags: android, location, geocoding, arabic

I have the following code:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.US /*getDefault()*/);
try {
   addresses=geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),loc.getLongitude(),1);                  
...
```

I'm using Locale.US (and I tried also Locale.English) but for several streets, I get an Arabic street name. I read about it and it seems to be a problem on the Geocoder side but I was wondering if other people managed to bypass this problem or maybe let me know where can I report this in order for this to be fixed (I wonder how come it wasn't fix so far).

Comment: Is your Location `loc` in a position where Arabic street names would be expected? Changing the Locale, as far as I am aware, is not going to translate street names.

Comment: The streets are in Israel where the names are in Hebrew. For the streets that works OK (most of them), I get the name in English and is pronounced correctly.

Comment: Can you share the lat, lng of the faulty street name with us?

Comment: lat:long - 32.094098,34.817184